# Porque pydantic me cambia letras por minusculas?

Tags: python-3.x

Estoy tratando de consumir un servicio, pero al momento de trabajar con pydantic este me cambia algunas letras mayusculas por minusculas..

```
{'client_id': '4fbcca9e-b623-48fa-afe5-03a0c469f2af', 'grant_type': 'client_credentials', 'client_secret': 'iAh39TySkZrFoLECR3O3hxRQlPir3p0uJGdnxUH5'}
{'client_id': '4Fbcca9E-B623-48Fa-Afe5-03A0C469F2Af', 'grant_type': 'client_credentials', 'client_secret': 'iAh39TySkZrFoLECR3O3hxRQlPir3p0uJGdnxUH5'}
```

Es algo raro, porque el servicio que intento consumir es muy sensible a estas cosas, pero es raro ya que no me habia pasado

el modelo lo he creado normal

```
class modelTest(BaseModel):
     client_id: str
     grant_type: str
     client_secret: str

def ser_test():
   test = modelTest(**g.body)
```

No es la gran cosa.. solo que me esta ocasionando problemas con esto

espero me puedan ayudar, gracias!

Comment: ¿por qué supones que es Pydantic el que te lo ha cambiado? ¿Cómo inicializas `client_id` y de dónde salen los dos ejemplos que pones al inicio de la pregunta ?

Comment: entendiendo que estoy usando flask, utilizo g.body para asignarlo al modelo, y solo eso mas, los valores el primero es la impresion del modelo, la segunda es el post que mando

Comment: Sigue faltándome información. A la vista de la sintaxis que usas en el ejemplo, `g.body` es algún tipo de diccionario ¿de dónde ha salido? ¿Qué ves en pantalla si haces un `print(g.body)`?